# How to make my discord bot delete an nsfw word and not another sfw word that contains the nsfw word? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I made my discord bot delete nsfw words whenever it encounters them. But, I encountered a problem.
I had the word "turd" in my list. But whenever someone said "saturday", it got deleted too.

How do I make it so that the word alone gets deleted, and not an instance of it in another sfw word? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.client.attempts = {}

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, msg):
        for word in file:
            if word in msg.content.lower():
                await msg.delete()
                attempts = 0
                try:
                    self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] += 1
                except KeyError:
                    self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] = 1

                #the person gets muted if they say the same nsfw word 3 times in a row.

                if self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] == 3:
                    muted_role = msg.author.guild.get_role(783622936837226529)
                    await msg.author.add_roles(muted_role)
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title='',
                        description='',
                        colour=discord.Colour.red()
                    )
                    embed.add_field(name=f"✅ {msg.author.display_name} has been muted.", value='Reason: Toxicity')
                    await msg.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1800)
                    await msg.author.remove_roles(muted_role)
                    break

                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: what about adding a space character before and after the word you want to filter?

Comment: You're checking if the word is in the content of the message. Try to check if the word is in a splitted version of the content (like split the content with a space as a seperator)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. However, this is an inefficient method

```py
for word in file:
    if word in msg.content.lower():
        if msg.content.lower() in ["saturday"]: return
```

You could use regex

```py
import re
def string_found(word, content):
    if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(word) + r"\b", content):
        return True
    return False

for word in file:
    if string_found(word, message.content.lower()) or string_found(string + "s", message.content.lower()):
```